# esp32 board crashes

Tags: esp32

I try to connect sensors to esp32 board. when connecting a sensor, for example, DHT11, but it happens with others as well the board enter into a loop of boots with the following error

```
19:36:37.440 -> rst:0x10 (RTCWDT_RTC_RESET),boot:0x13(SPI_FAST_FLASH_BOOT) 
19:36:37.440 -> flash read err, 1000
19:36:37.440 -> ets_main.c 371 
19:36:37.772 -> ets Jun  8 2016 00:22:57
```

I tried to upload the board with led connected between the Vout and the GND and same thing happens.

any idea? where is the problem? blink catch with led connected between GND and a pin work fine.
I attach the board picture

many thanks,

Gilad

[image]

Comment: does the board work correctly when no sensors are connected?

Comment: "I tried to upload the board with led connected between the Vout and the GND", what is that for? Are you connecting an LED between Vcc and GND without a resistor?

Comment: @jsotola, Yes without sensors it works fine, can connect to wifi, upload data to firebase and blink led

Comment: @hcheung with a resistor. I thought to debug if the problem is with the sensor or the connection to Vout-GND. I connect the Vout to the CLK pin in the picture

Comment: I don't see a Vout on the board in the picture and the description of your setup is not very clear to me. Make sure you're not connecting pins carrying 5V directly to any pins of the ESP32 (which is a 3.3V device). Could you describe how you connect the sensor or show a schematic?

Comment: A flash read error might occur when you have the wrong partition scheme selected. Try with board type "ESP-dev-module" and a 4MB partition scheme.